# Can I use proxy for whole script of python using dns.resolver and smtplib in it?

Tags: python, python-2.7, proxy, dns, smtplib

```
    import dns.resolver
    import socket
    import smtplib
    import socks
```

I am adding proxy here:

```
    PROXY = '196.89.10.16'
    PROXY_PORT = 8080

    socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS4, PROXY, PROXY_PORT , True)
    socks.wrapmodule(smtplib)
```

I am getting dns mxrecord:

```
    records = dns.resolver.query('gmail.com', 'MX')
    mxRecord = records[0].exchange
    mxRecord = str(mxRecord)
    print mxRecord

    server = smtplib.SMTP()
    server.set_debuglevel(0)
```

Connecting to mxRecord:

```
    server.connect(mxRecord)
    server.helo('hello')
    print server.helo_resp

    server.mail('example@example.org')  
    addressToVerify = 'example@gmail.com'
```

I am verifying if account exist or not here:

```
    code, message = server.rcpt(str(addressToVerify))

    print code
    print message
    #returns 250 on success
    # Assume 250 as Success
    if code == 250:
        print('Success')
    else:
        print('Bad')
```

I want to add proxy to call `rcpt` function.

Please help.